# iOS After OCR a busniss card,how can save these info to my model?

Tags: ios

I use Tesseract and OpenCV to OCR a busniss card,then got a long string.
I want save the info to my model ,such as save name to model.name,save email to model.email and so on. Because of the busniss cards' layout are different, so,how can I do that?

Comment: how many possible layouts are there ??? and what could possibly change ??? and remain same ?

Comment: The number of layouts is unknown.Everyone will choose a business card according to their own proferences.Therefore,the corresponding info connot be obtained by preset layout in project.

Comment: Ok what will be the format of output string ??? Can you please share some code snippet???